# command line method to update/add a DNS entry (the host NOT the server...)

Tags: windows-10, dns

I'm looking for a way to add or update an entry in windows' DNS table from the command line.  I've found lots and lots of posts that describe how to change the DNS **server**, but that's not what I want.  I want something that allows me to basically say "resolve foo.bar.net to address a.b.c.d".

Is there a way to do this **without** editing the windows \etc\hosts file each time I want to make a change?  I would think that the hosts file isn't both the configuration file AND the actual database/cache/table, right?   I'd expect this to be something simple, but I certainly can't seem to find it easily (I think because all the responses are about changing the server rather than the host itself)

Comment: On linux it is straightforward with dnsmasq

Comment: "windows DNS table" is confusing, please clarify.  Is this for Windows Server? (You'd use MMC with the DNS service).  Is this for Windows 7/8/10 Home/Pro not domain-joined?  Then you'd need to do what you're asking for on the configured DNS system it's using.  Etc.

Comment: No, this is for a standard win10 machine (i.e. not a server.  I just want to be able to override a couple learned DNS entries manually).